# Pandas - Extract rows until a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe.

```
    value TRUE/FALSE
0       1          T
1       2          T
2       3          T
3       4          T
4       4          T
5       4          T
6       4          T
7       4          F
8       4          F
9       4          F
10      4          F
11      4          F
12      4          F
13      4          F
14      4          T
15      4          T
16      4          T
17      4          T
18      4          F
19      4          T
20      4          F
```

I would like to extract all rows with 'T' label until first 'F' label occurs.

Expected output:

```
   value TRUE/FALSE
0      1          T
1      2          T
2      3          T
3      4          T
4      4          T
5      4          T
6      4          T
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html) on the boolean Series `df['TRUE/FALSE'].eq('T')`, this will yield True until the first F/False is found:

```
df[df['TRUE/FALSE'].eq('T').cummin()]
```

Alternative with [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html):

```
df[df['TRUE/FALSE'].eq('T').cumprod().eq(1)]
```

output:

```
   value TRUE/FALSE
0      1          T
1      2          T
2      3          T
3      4          T
4      4          T
5      4          T
6      4          T
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1,2,3]+[4]*18,
                   'TRUE/FALSE': list('TTTTTTTFFFFFFFTTTTFTF')})
```

Comment: Works perfect ! Thank you ..

Comment: @JayashreeSridhar I updated the answer to use "T"/"F" strings in place of True/False